# HTML indent table

Tags: html, css, jsf

```
    <table class="layout-table">
    <tr>
        <td><strong>3. Has the person completed all required training within the past three years?</strong><br/><br/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>a. Copy of It</strong>
            <p:selectOneRadio id="radio3" value="#{question3a}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="0" />&#160;&#160;&#160;
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="1" />&#160;&#160;&#160;
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="NA" itemValue="2" />&#160;&#160;&#160;
            </p:selectOneRadio>
            <br/>
            <h:outputText id="counter3" />
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

What I am trying to do is get a table to look like this

```
   3. Has the person completed all required training within the past three years?
          a. Copy of It     Yes []     No[]    NA[]
          b. (another one)  Yes []     No[]    NA[]
```

I dont know how to tab the a and b and also if I make it where the buttons are to the right of the columns then it spaces it all the way to the very right hand side and I am not sure why.... Is this possible to do without CSS? If not then CSS would be fine too. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This looks like a job for an [ordered list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol), not tables.

Comment: *Nested* ordered lists, no less; it definitely resembles some non-tabular information.

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes, you're right, nested ordered lists is the way to go

Comment: yeah tables are tricky things, very handy for some things, like scale-proof centering something on the page with only css. But for other things, like what you want, you're really better off using something else like the suggestions above. You can't indent part of a table; a table is always a grid of rows and cells. Another thing is that tables always scale to fit what's inside them. Handy for centering as previously mentioned, but not if you're looking for a custom layout like your tabs..

Comment: Ok thanks guys! I guess table is not the way :P. Thanks!!!

Comment: You should show the HTML markup, not code that generates it, and you should clarify whether the markup is fixed or not and what you are really up to. It now seems that you are using a layout table when other type of formatting would be simpler and *not* using a table for the tabular data you have—instead, no-break spaces are used for kind-of “tabbing”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to mark it up so it looks like this. I do agree that tables probably aren't the best solution for this problem.

```
<table class="layout-table">
   <tr>
      <td><strong>3. Has the person completed all required training within the past three years?</strong> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="margin: 0 auto;">
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <p:selectOneRadio id="radio3" value="#{question3a}">
                     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="0" />&#160;&#160;&#160;
                     <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="1" />&#160;&#160;&#160;
                     <f:selectItem itemLabel="NA" itemValue="2" />&#160;&#160;&#160;
                  </p:selectOneRadio>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <p:selectOneRadio id="radio3" value="#{question3a}">
                     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="0" />&#160;&#160;&#160;
                     <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="1" />&#160;&#160;&#160;
                     <f:selectItem itemLabel="NA" itemValue="2" />&#160;&#160;&#160;
                  </p:selectOneRadio>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```