# Aligning columns in divs made to look like an HTML table with left padding

Tags: html, css, layout, alignment, html-table

I have the following layout in my admin section. It is styled and laid out like a table, however I am using unordered lists and divs.

[image]

I am using some padding to tab in the "row" to represent a tree structure and allow me to use a jQuery plugin for sorting a structure based on the nested set model.

The following markup is the section I have highlighted in red in the screenshot.

```
<ul>
    <li id="menuItem_6" class="mjs-nestedSortable-branch mjs-nestedSortable-expanded" data-tree-level="1">
        <div class="ui-sortable-handle" data-id="6">
            <span class="child_rows" style="width: 5%;">
            <span class="child_rows" style="width: 35%;">
            <a href="/app_dev.php/administration/golf/category/6/update/">Releases</a>
            </span>
            <span class="child_rows text-right" style="width: 50px;"> 2 </span>
            <span class="text-right child_rows" style="width: 250px;"> 09-07-2015 15:44 by crmpicco </span>
            <span class="child_rows buttons" style="width: auto;"></span>
        </div>
        <ul>...another row in here...</ul>
        <ul>...another row in here...</ul>
        <ul>...another row in here...</ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My question is - **is there a way to align the columns so that "Assets" and "Last Updated" are aligned correctly**?

Here is a fiddle to show my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/crmpicco/afwsduq0/

Comment: Any chance of getting a https://jsfiddle.net/

Much easier to fix the problem with the full code that's affecting it.

Comment: Don't use padding on the whole row, apply it to the first column in the row. You'll probably have to put the icon and the link inside another container.

Comment: @JayMoy Sure, I should have provided this up front. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5o8usjy2/ Just removed `padding-left: 20px;` Is this what you are looking for

Comment: No, sorry that wasn't it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all, this is tabular data and for this kind of data you should always use tables.

Now, if you want your columns to be aligned, all you have to do is to remove the padding from the **ul** element. But I think this won't be an option for you because you want the child entries to be indented, which can't be done with list elements without shifting the column alignment.

What you have here seems like a nested table and you should solve it by using tables (don't worry, jQuery drag and drop is available for table rows too) and expandable table rows to show their children or another different page entirely (be it ajax or non-ajax loaded) that will do that.

A solution would be to use jQuery, ids and data attributes like so:

```
<tr id="1" class="table-row" data-parent-id="#0">
    <td>Row content</td>
</tr>

<tr id="2" class="table-row" data-parent-id="#1">
    <td>Row content</td>
</tr>
```

Your jQuery should look something like this:

```
$('.table-row').each(function() {
    var parent = $(this).data('parent-id');
    var parentPadding = $(parent).css('padding-left');

    if(parent != '#0') {
        $(this).css('padding-left', parentPadding + 20);
    }
});
```

Comment: Check this question's answer out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939965/html-indent-table